# How can you use SessionAsSigner in a Java Bean called from an XPage?

Tags: javabeans, xpages, xpages-ssjs

According to Phillip Riand (see: [discussion on openNTF](http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/66d9103768cc2fed85256c59006b5433/7ed6124389b50293862579b6005a3af7!OpenDocument)) this is not possible... They need  to know the design element to find out who signed it. Therefore, it is only available in SSJS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I know of to use the **sessionAsSigner** object in Java beans:

1 By resolving the sessionAsSigner object:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Session sessionAsSigner = context.getApplication().getVariableResolver().
        resolveVariable(context, "sessionAsSigner");
```

2 By using the **getCurrentSessionAsSigner()** function from the **com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil** class in the Extension Library.

To be able to use it (in Java as wel as SSJS) you'll want to make sure that all design elements were signed by the same user ID. If that's not the case, the sessionAsSigner object will not be available ('undefined').

Comment: Ahh... interesting. I normally use DominoUtils.getSession() - and that class does not have the sessionAsSigner. I did not know it existed in the ExtLibUtil class. Thank you! - and yes, I know you must sign all elements with the same id for it to work ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I found that the solution is right at hand :-)

I changed my XPage (in this example an XAgent) to:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false">

This is an xAgent returning json data...

<xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:Controller.verify(sessionAsSigner)}]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
```

and in the bean I simply used the session in the argument when I needed to open a database/document as signer. Sometimes the solution is so simple :-)

/John

Comment: Nice little example of the principles known as [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Love it!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! In our case, a single signer is much more difficult to maintain than a single singer... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old post that I just stumbled upon. Tried some of the solutions mentioned above:

1. `resolveVariable` did not work for me, at least not for `sessionAsSigner` as this throws a runtime error (I can resolve plain old `session`, though...)
2. to be honest I didn't quite understand the Controller.verify(sessionAsSigner) method; is Controller something specific to XAgents? If so, I don't have an XAgent here, so can't use it
3. didn't feel like importing extra ExtLib classes here...

So I came up with another solution that appears to be very simple:

created a method in my javaBean that takes a session object as argument; since sessionAsSigner belongs to the same class as session I don't have to import something new.

Javacode is:

```
public void testSession(Session s) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(" > test effective user for this session = " 
             + s.getEffectiveUserName());
}
```

This is called from SSJS as either

```
mybean.testSession(session);
```

or

```
myBean.testSession(sessionAsSigner);
```

Maybe helps others, too

Comment: this is exactly what I do... My bean is called "Controller" and the method "verify" :-)

Comment: Argh, I should have thought of that; my personal java experience still needs a lot of improvement, you know; at my current stage I'm only capable of thinking step-by-step :D - thanks for pointing out