# Notes Java App can't call agent.runWithDocumentContext()

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm creating TestNG tests for Java classes that are normally used from Xpages application. Since they have to call some legacy LotusScript code, I have to use agent.runWithDocumentContext call.

From Xpages this runs fine. But when I call this method from TestNG suite run from Domino Designer, I get

**NotesException: Unable to pass doc context - Caller must run with user authority**

I create session normally using NotesFactory.createSession()

Database is on test server and agent has Run As Web User property set, since it is called correctly form xpages in the app.

Everything runs on 9.0.1 Domino

Comment: Martin, were you able to solve this? Have the same issue: need to access Domino legacy stuff from separate Java standalone application (on GlassFish), and getting the same Exception. Notes Session initialize in the same way: NotesFactory.createSession(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a hint how to solve your problem, to get your code to run in a user context.

[I want my Domino Servlet to get an authenticated user session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771700/i-want-my-domino-servlet-to-get-an-authenticated-user-session)